# What is this sound my HDD has started making?

Tags: hard-drive, debian, hardware-failure

[This clip is a recording I've just made](https://youtu.be/kmCJYh4wjLI) of the sound a new 4TB WD RED drive has started making roughly every forty minutes. It started occurring *before* setting up `hd-idle` (an alternative to `hdparm`), and I cannot think of what's causing it, or if I should be alarmed.

The drive performs as expected, and is presently in a low-use server running Debian 11.

Thank you,

Mike

Comment: Could be nothing unusual, especially if SMART data still looks benign.  Change the acoustic vs performance mode of the HDD if you want a quieter drive.

Comment: So far so good, it seems

`Bad Sectors: 0 sectors
Powered On: 14.1 days
Power Cycles: 1
Average Powered On Per Power Cycle: 14.1 days
Temperature: 34.0 C
Attribute Parsing Verification: Good
Overall Status: GOOD`

Answer (score 0):

The clip is short, but not any noise any of my drives ever made.

First, back up important data.

Second, get the WD Hard Drive test app and test the complete drive for errors.

**should [I] be alarmed.**    <-- I would be.

So for sure test it.

**Follow up:**

In a comment, you say the drive is new. So then return it for a replacement if you can.

Comment: I would be alarmed. Thank goodness it's performing right now.

Comment: Even if the noise abates for a bit, back it up and test it.

Comment: Will do, cheers. I suppose I can shut it off until I can remove it into a non-linux system with support for that app.

Comment: Its important you back it up ASAP (before testing it) and dont write any data exclusively to it you care about.

Answer (score 0):

You should be pulling your data off that drive as fast as possible - that drive is faulty and will likely die soon.

I dont recognise the buzzing, but my guess is the "a" at the end of the clip is the head arm retracting suddenly.  It sounds a little like how hard drives used to sound when parking the heads many,many years ago

Comment: Thank you for your concern. The contents of the drive are thankfully of little value to me and already exist on other drives across machines. I suppose I am more worried about damage to the system, or perhaps if this is something I should be concerned about in terms of longevity. I'm surprised a drive so new exhibits this.